# SSRS Report Manager Exporting to Excel Pagenames

Tags: reporting-services

I've created a report which on manual export from SSRS shows the pagenames i've specified, "sales", "Marketing", "HR".

However when i deploy to report manager on the server and export from there i only get "Sheet1", "Sheet2" etc

Does Report Manager allow page names?

Answer (score 3):

[Worksheet name support](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/bretupdegraff/bidn-blog/234/new-features-of-ssrs-2008-r2-part-1-naming-excel-sheets-when-exporting-reports) was added to SSRS 2008 R2. Is your server possibly at a lower revision than your local dev environment?

Comment: We use SSRS 2008 R2 but the server/ database is 2005. We've installed 2008 for the added functionality.  I'm using SSRS 2008 and Report manager 2008

Comment: Then my answer is your problem. Excel worksheet names require 2008R2.